# using third party api on watson assistant

Tags: javascript, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, openweathermap

i'm using the [open weather map api](https://openweathermap.org/current) in order to get information on the current weather and then integrate it with watson assistant (i used [this as a reference](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/develop-app.html#building-a-client-application) for the watson assistant code) before deploying on the terminal. here's my code:

```
var city = "Seattle";
weather.setCity(city);
function processResponse(err, response){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        var endConversation = false;
        if(response.intents[0]){
            if(response.intents[0].intent=="CurrentWeather"){
                 weather.getDescription(function(err, desc){
                     weather.getTemperature(function(err, temp){
                         console.log("It is " + desc + " today with a temperature of " + temp + " degrees Celsius.");
                     )};
                 )};
            }
            else if(response.intents[0].intent=="end_conversation"){
                console.log(response.output.text);
                endConversation = true;
            }
        }
        if(!endConversation){
            var newMessageFromUser = prompt(">> ");
            service.message({
                workspace_id: workspace_id,
                input: {
                    text: newMessageFromUser
                },
                context: response.context
            },processResponse);
        }
}
```

it works, but then the response looks like this:

```
>> what is the weather today in seattle
>>
It is few clouds today with a temperature of 29 degrees Celsius.
>> bye
['See ya!']
```

whenever i use any third party apis, instead of responding right after i enter the trigger keywords, the terminal asks me to input another entry (in the scenario above, i entered nothing) before responding. however, when i try to enter keywords related to intents whose responses are just retrieved right away from the watson assistant (as is with end_conversation), the terminal responds right away.

Is there a way for me to force the terminal to only ask once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following [Michal Bida's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980049/using-third-party-api-on-watson-assistant#comment92913273_52981957), I tried implementing the third party API in cloud function and it worked. simply created a php function using the [php implementation of the openweather map api](https://github.com/cmfcmf/OpenWeatherMap-PHP-Api) and followed the steps on how to create an action in php through [this tutorial](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_actions.html#creating-php-actions). for the implementation, i followed [this tutorial](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html#action-client-example) on how to implement actions in watson assistant. it now works even when directly invoked from the chat bot at the side of the watson assistant.

an example of a response it returns will be:

```
{"weather":"It is raining today in Seattle with a temperature of 15 degrees Celsius"}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to get around entering something before the actual response.

Take a look at [client-based dialog actions](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html#action-client-example). The key is to use the `skip_user_input` flag and check it within your application. Basically, it would indicate to your application that you need to process some data. The app would it send back to Watson Assistant to respond. [There is also the server-based dialog action](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html). In that case Watson Assistant is invoking an IBM Cloud Functions action. [A tutorial using that approach is here, interfacing with a Db2 database](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html).

Another technique is what I call [replaced markers](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/watson-conversation-variables#replaced-markers). You would have Watson Assistant returns an answer with placeholders. Your app would replace those markers.

Third, you are using JavaScript with asynchronous processing. It seems that your empty prompt is processed while you fetch the weather data. The IF for the weather is independent of the empty prompt. Try fixing that.

Comment: do you have any suggestions on how i could fix the if clause for the weather?

Comment: I am no JavaScript expert, but you could probably use Promises

Comment: I would add that you can also use cloud function to make a call to third part API and return the response back to dialog. We have used this in the past to create a weather app ourselves. Worked fine.

Comment: incorporated the server actions

Comment: @MichalBida can this be done using a lite/free account?

Comment: @xjm Well from https://console.bluemix.net/openwhisk/learn/pricing (29.10.2018), if your cloud function executes in 500ms and its memory limit is 128MB then you get 5,000,000 calls per month for free... But check the web for more details.

Comment: @MichalBida i've created a cloud foundry space as it says but i keep getting "No Cloud Foundry Space" when i open console.bluemix.net/openwhisk/create so I thought it might have been because of pricing

Comment: @xjm Afaik you need to select proper region (I use us-south) then you need to have cloud foundry organization and inside that organization you need to have cloud foundry space. You can set this in the cloud UI when you select Functions -> Actions then in the upper left part of the page. For some reason for me the defaults are always blank - so this might be the reason? If this won't help I would try to contact IBM cloud support (forums or directly...)...

Comment: @MichalBida thanks, that did the trick for me! i'll try implementing it now.